# filter table from database in jsp using jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

I am retrieving data from database and putting into table. I have combo box to select type.On change of combo box I want to filter data from database.I want to use jquery in jsp.

Below is code for select type

```
    <form method="post" action="dashboardcontrol.jsp">
            Type: <select name="type" id="type">
                <option value="select" selected>..select..</option>
                <option value="agriculture">Agriculture</option>
                <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value="Religion">Religion</option>
                <option value="music">Music</option>    
            </select> 
           <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    </form>
```

this is the table which contain all data

```
<TD><%=resultset.getInt(1)%></TD>
<TD><%=resultset.getString(2)%></TD>
<TD><%=resultset.getString(3)%></TD>
<TD><%=resultset.getString(4)%></TD>
<TD><%=resultset.getString(5)%></TD>
<TD><%=resultset.getString(6)%></TD>
```

Any advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

function getSelectedComboBoxValue(boxValue) {

if(boxValue!="select") {

$.ajax({

```
    type : "POST",
    url : "getDatabaseRecordClassName",
    data : {
        BOXVALUE : boxValue,
    },
    success : function(data) {
        if(data!=""){
           $("#tab_container").html(data);
        }
    }
```

}

}

}

```
<form method="post" action="dashboardcontrol.jsp">
        Type: <select name="type" id="type" onchange="getSelectedComboBoxValue(this.value)">
            <option value="select">..select..</option>
            <option value="agriculture">Agriculture</option>
            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Religion">Religion</option>
            <option value="music">Music</option>    
        </select> 
</form>
```

Here "getDatabaseRecordClassName" is Java Class Name.
Here "#tab_container" is table DIV id.